# Convert a value with a regex to a real value

Tags: vbscript

I have a huge file containing values with a regex in it, like this:

```
LGP0041_\d{4}\.dta
objd135a_\S{3}.txt
```

Now I need to convert these to a valid example value, like this:

```
LGP0041_1234.dta
objd135a_abc.txt
```

I know of the `RegExp` object to check if there is a match, but is there also a way to create valid values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular **grammar** can be used to recognize or produce words of its language, but the VBScript regexp **engine** does not implement producing. So you have to roll your own.

Your sample does not contain contain regular patterns. `\S` can't mean 'non-whitespace' because you won't like characters illegal in a file name and a representative sample of file names should contain elements with spaces. The fact that the first sample escapes the extension dot and the second one doesn't makes me think that your syntax specs aren't really thought out. If you come up with a (regular) grammar of your inputs, I'm willing to give your problem further thought.

**Some code to base the thinking on:**

```
Option Explicit

Function rndInt(lowerbound, upperbound)
  rndInt = Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
End Function

Sub shuffleAD(aX)
' Durstenfeld's Permutation Algorithm
    Dim J, K, Temp
    For J = UBound(aX) To 1 Step -1
        K = Int((J + 1) * Rnd) ' random number 0 - J
        Temp  = aX(J)
        aX(J) = aX(K)
        aX(K) = Temp
    Next
End Sub ' shuffleAD

Class cRGen
  Private m_
  Public Function init(s)
    Set init = Me
    ReDim m_(Len(s) - 1)
    Dim i
    For i = 0 To UBound(m_)
        m_(i) = Mid(s, i + 1, 1)
    Next
  End Function
  Public Function getNext(mi, ma)
    shuffleAD m_
    getNext = Mid(Join(m_, ""), 1, rndInt(mi, ma))
  End Function
End Class

Dim goRpl : Set goRpl = Nothing
Function magic(m, w, mi, ma, p, src)
  If IsEmpty(ma) Then ma = mi
  magic = goRpl.m_dicGens(w).getNext(mi, ma)
End Function

Class cRpl
  Private m_fRpl
  Private m_r
  Public  m_dicGens
  Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_fRpl    = GetRef("magic")
    Set m_r       = New RegExp
    m_r.Pattern   = "\\(\w){(\d+)(?:,(\d+))?}"
    Set m_dicGens = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set m_dicGens("d") = New cRGen.init("0123456789")
    Set m_dicGens("S") = New cRGen.init("abcdefghij")
  End Sub
  Public Function rpl(s)
    Set goRpl = me
    rpl = m_r.Replace(s, m_fRpl)
  End Function
End Class

Randomize
Dim aTests : aTests = Array( _
      "LGP0041_\d{4}.dta" _
    , "objd135a_\S{3}.txt" _
    , "x_\S{3,8}.txt" _
)
Dim oRpl : Set oRpl = New cRpl
Dim sTest
For Each sTest In aTests
    WScript.Echo sTest, "=>", oRpl.rpl(sTest)
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 28936688.vbs
LGP0041_\d{4}.dta => LGP0041_4317.dta
objd135a_\S{3}.txt => objd135a_cea.txt
x_\S{3,8}.txt => x_jgcfidh.txt

cscript 28936688.vbs
LGP0041_\d{4}.dta => LGP0041_8054.dta
objd135a_\S{3}.txt => objd135a_eci.txt
x_\S{3,8}.txt => x_ahfgd.txt
```

This should at least identify the needed components:

1. generators that deliver strings of specific character sets
2. a (sorry: global) replace function that maps 'type letters' to generators, handles 'width specs', and build the output
3. a regular pattern to parse the specs from your inputs

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that the regex examples I got delivered were not "official" ones and that I need to create my own translations. So I will use your examples as starting point.